# Check from code if web browser support 256bit encryption

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ssl

My client wants to block users from accessing the website if their browser does not support 256bit encryption. Is it possible to check it somehow from client / server code?

Website will be running on HTTPS and the SSL certificate that is issued to the domain would be set to use 256bit encryption. So I think that it must automatically prevent anyone from accessing it because they would get some kind of certificate error otherwise - but I don't know for sure.

The project is in ASP.NET.

Comment: It is .NET. I've just added this information to the question. On the server side we've got C# (ASP.NET 4.0), client side - jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTTPS_KEYSIZE`.

```
var keySize = Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS_KEYSIZE"];
```